# Why does step 2 in migrating files to media try to insert to the nid from the source and not the target?

Tags: migrations

I am doing a migration as per this example https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file_to_media/issues/3118471. Migration and step 1 work fine, I get this error when running step 2. I also tried running the migration with an --update flag (drush mim migd8_blog_media_step2 --update) and get the same error .  its trying to do an insert instead of an update. **And its trying to insert into the source nid, not the target nid.**

Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title'[error]cannot be null: INSERT INTO {​​​​​node_field_data}​​​​​ (nid, vid, type, langcode, status, uid, title, created, changed, promote, sticky,
default_langcode, revision_translation_affected, publish_on, unpublish_on) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
:db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
:db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8,
:db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12,
:db_insert_placeholder_13, :db_insert_placeholder_14); Array
(
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 22610

This is the id of the source node, not the target
The migration file I am using contains the following lines.

```yaml
# This migration links the newly created media entities with entity reference field on the target bundle.
id: migd8_blog_media_step2
label: blog Media Mapping
source:
  key: migrate
  plugin: d7_node
  node_type: blog_entry
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  default_bundle: blog
process: 
  nid: nid
  changed: changed
  field_files:
    plugin: file_id_lookup
    source: field_main_image
    migration: migd8_blog_media_step1
    no_stub: true
migration_dependencies:
  optional:
  - migd8_node_blog
  - migd8_blog_media_step1
```

this is my step 1:

```
# File to Media Migration configuration for blog Media migration

id: migd8_blog_media_step1
label: blog Media Step 1
migration_group: cncs
source:
  key: migrate
  plugin: media_entity_generator_d7
  entity_type: node
  bundle: blog_entry
  langcode: und
  d7_file_url: 'https://www.nationalservice.gov/sites/default/files/'
  #d7_file_url: 'public://'
  field_names:
    - field_main_image

destination:
  plugin: entity:media

process:
    
  bundle:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: image

  # Using the alt tag if available, else the file name.
  name:
    plugin: media_name
    source: file_name

  # This process plugin will skip the whole row if a existing media is found.
  existing_media_file:
    plugin: check_media_duplicate
    source: target_id

  # This process plugin will skip the whole row if a duplicate image is found.
  unique_file_id:
    plugin: check_duplicate
    source: target_id
    
  # Map the field 
  
  
  field_media_image/alt: alt
  field_media_image/title: title
  field_media_image/target_id:
    plugin: media_file_copy
    move: FALSE
    reuse: TRUE
    path: 'public://images/'
    source: file_path

  langcode: langcode
   
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
`
```

here is my main migration yml :

```
id: 

migd8_node_blog
label: Custom node migration from Drupal 7
migration_group: cncs
deriver: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeDeriver
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migd8_node_blog_node
source:
 plugin: migd8_node_blog_node # use custom source plugin
 node_type: blog_entry
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  bundle: blog
process:
  'path/pathauto':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0 # Disable pathauto.
  'path/alias': alias
  type: 
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: blog
  status: status
  uid: 
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  title: title
  langcode:
    plugin: static_map
    bypass: true
    source: language
    map:
      und: en
  created: created
  changed: changed
  promote: promote
  field_blog_tags:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    source: field_blog_tags
    migration: migrate_taxonomy
  sticky: sticky
  body:
      plugin: sub_process
      source: body
      process:
        value: value
        summary: summary
        format:
          plugin: default_value
          default_value: full_html
  field_blog_author: field_blog_author        
  field_blog_post_date_: 
    plugin: iterator
    source: field_blog_post_date_
    process:
      value:
        plugin: substr
        source: value
        start: 0
        length: 10
```

I realize its looking for the source nid in this query , not the target nid
Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title'[error]cannot be null: INSERT INTO {​​​​​node_field_data}​​​​​ (nid, vid, type, langcode, status, uid, title, created, changed, promote, sticky,
default_langcode, revision_translation_affected, publish_on, unpublish_on) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
:db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
:db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8,
:db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12,
:db_insert_placeholder_13, :db_insert_placeholder_14); Array
(
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 22610
**22610 is the node id in the source.
in the target its a totally different nid**

Comment: Change `bundle: blog` to `node_type: blog`  and flush all caches.

Comment: destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  node_type: blog. I still get the same error

Comment: Missing bundle for entity type node                                                                             [error]
(/var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php:108)
migd8_blog_media_step2 Migration - 2133 failed.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a backtrace, to see where your error really comes from .. Install [past](https://www.drupal.org/project/past) and make it take over your watchdog entries. There should then be the backtrace for your error ... or give XDEBUG a chance, you'll love it.

Comment: I no longer get this missing bundle error , i fixed that by putting default_bundle: blog but now it is trying to do an insert of new content instead of an update

Comment: Could you please show also step1 and the definition

Comment: Just by a quick first look, it seems you're missing the Deriver class ?

Comment: i am doing it per this link, there is no Deriver class https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file_to_media/issues/3118471

Comment: There is one!
deriver: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeDeriver

Comment: oh i see 
id: mig_article_node
label: Article Node
description: Config for mig article node migration
deriver: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeDeriver

Comment: I added the deriver as above and reran everything i still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i imported the new nodes with the same nid as the old ones using

```
nid: nid
```

in the process
that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

As the [Migrating nodes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-nodes) doc shows, it needs to be:

```
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  default_bundle: blog
```

Comment: Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:    [error]
1048 Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {node_field_data} (nid, vid, type, langcode, status, uid, title,

Comment: @Diana does your **config/install/migrate_plus.migration.mig_blog_node.yml** have `title: title` under `process:` just like in [the link](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file_to_media/issues/3118471) ?

Comment: If I put in a title it creates new content . It’s doing an insert it should be doing an update at this point . The node already exists just trying to attach the media to it

Comment: What version of Drush, migration_tools, migrate_file_to_media, and migrate_plus are you using? I can't get step1 to work, it always gets ignored.

Comment: @Diana I updated my answer with my best guest since I can't try it myself. You might have to put back the `title: title`

Comment: if i put in the title it starts inserting duplicate data

Comment: Data as in duplicate nodes? Or ???

Comment: yes it starts adding new nodes with the nid of the source